# Jekyll website cannot convert markdown and liquid to html properly with "github-pages" Jekyll plugins

Tags: html, markdown, jekyll, github-pages, liquid

I have create a Jekyll website locally. It works fine with "bundle exec jekyll serve".

But after the following operations, my website cannot convert markdown and liquid code to html properly.

**This is how I install "github-pages" in my project.**

1. Adding "gem "github-pages", group: :jekyll_plugins" in Gemfile,
2. "sudo bundle install && sudo bundle update"

**Before adding github-pages plugins**
[image]

**After adding github-pages plugins and running "bundle exec jekyll serve"**
[image]

It cannot convert markdown block properly. Who can help me with that,, I really appreciate it.
Here is my jekyll website [code repos](https://github.com/bladewangpro/bladewangpro.github.io)

Answer (score 4):

I have solved this issue. In local Jekyll website, {{ page.content }} is identified as "markdown + liquid" code snippet.

**Somehow, Github-pages cannot recognize the markdown part in {{ page.content }}, we need to use filter to tell Gitpages there are markdown code snippets in {{ page.content }} explicitly.**

```
{{ page.content | markdownify | liquify }}
```